# VB.NET: UDP beginreceive method throws NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, udp

```
   Public udpReceivingClient As UdpClient   
   udpReceivingClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf MT_RX_Callback, Nothing)
```

throws `NullReferneceException`.

How to use beginreceive method in UDP ? what mistake am I making ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your complete code? You haven't assigned anything to the udpReceivingClient variable, hence it causes a Null Reference when you try to use it. Additionally, the UdpClient requires some information before you can use it, such as which port to listen to.

```
    Public udpReceivingClient As UdpClient = New UdpClient(port_number)
```

[Turning on Option Explicit will help you avoid these errors.](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/311329)

Comment: Turning on Option Explicit will not help with a null reference exception

Comment: @MattWilko Yes, you're right. I'm not sure what I was thinking, except that "it's 5am and I've been up far too long." Option Explicit/Strict is a good idea anyway, and I find myself posting that link in many answers.